# Navigating to a new view from login screen

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui

I am fairly new at Swiftui and have testing out login screens and got it to work but I am unable to find a way to make it so when on a successful login it goes to a new view.

```
import SwiftUI

let lightGreyColor = Color(red: 239.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, opacity: 1.0)
let storedUsername = "Myusername"
let storedPassword = "Mypassword"

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    @State var authenticationDidFail: Bool = false
    @State var authenticationDidSucceed: Bool = false
    @State var editingMode: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                VStack {
                    WelcomeText()
                    UserImage()
                    UsernameTextField(username: $username)
                    PasswordSecureField(password: $password)
                    if authenticationDidFail {
                        Text("Information not correct. Try again.")
                            .offset(y: -10)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        if self.username == storedUsername && self.password == storedPassword {
                            self.authenticationDidSucceed = true
                            self.authenticationDidFail = false
                        } else {
                            self.authenticationDidFail = true
                        }
                    }) {
                        LoginButtonContent()
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                if authenticationDidSucceed {
                    Text("Login Succeeded!")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 80)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        .cornerRadius(20.0)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            .offset(y: editingMode ? -150 : 0)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct WelcomeText: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Welcome")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
        }
    }
}

struct UserImage : View {
    var body: some View {
        return Image("userImage")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(UIImage(named:"userImage")!.size, contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .clipped()
            .cornerRadius(150)
            .padding(.bottom, 75)
    }
}

struct LoginButtonContent : View {
    var body: some View {
        return Text("LOGIN")
            .font(.headline)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
            .background(Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(15.0)
    }
}

struct UsernameTextField : View {
    @Binding var username: String
    var body: some View {
        return TextField("Username", text: $username)
            .padding()
            .background(lightGreyColor)
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
    }
}

struct PasswordSecureField : View {
    @Binding var password: String
    var body: some View {
        return SecureField("Password", text: $password)
            .padding()
            .background(lightGreyColor)
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

I have tried many different ways with NavigationLink and NavigationView with no luck. I have looked all through out stack overflow, youtube, websites, and different tutorials with still no luck. If someone is able to help me out that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Youll have to use navigationLink

```
            NavigationLink(destination: NewView()) {
                Text("Do Something")
            }
```

And youll have to use NavigationViews in replace of button as well.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview

Comment: With replacing the button with NavigationLink would it still run the code to determine if password is correct or incorrect?

Comment: As long as its within the action and you place it within the correct condition, yes.